# Open .aspx file in design view in VS 2003

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2003

I am using .NET Studio 2003 and Framework 1.1 for designing a Wen Application. I tried to include css and js files using the following lines of code. But after putting this lines VS dosen't allow me to view aspx file in design view. Showing alert with **"Could not open in Design view. Quote Values differently inside a '<%... "value" ...%>' block"**

What should I do to view page in design view by keeping ResolveUrl function as it is in LINK and Script tags?

```
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Style/header.css")%>">
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Style/tooltip.css")%>">
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Style/menu.css")%>">
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Style/dropcheckbox.css")%>">
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Style/DateTime.css")%>">
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Style/time.css")%>">
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Style/Common.css")%>">


<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/JSFiles/jQuery.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/JSFiles/header.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/JSFiles/menu.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/JSFiles/DateTime.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/JSFiles/time.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/JSFiles/dropcheckbox.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/JSFiles/common.js")%>"></script>
```

Comment: Can't remember if this works in 2003, but try dragging the CSS file from Solution Explorer onto the page in code view. Ditto for the JS files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Design view is known to be totally unreliable in VS 2003 and we configure all our instances to open code-behind by default (in Options) - for example, it will continually break your layout. I strongly recommend you do the same.

Comment: Ya..Design view is not much useful in VS 2003..ok I am taking your advise..thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is simply as stated - which unfortunately is not stated simply.

Change following statement

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/JSFiles/jQuery.js")%>"></script>
```

to (note I switched **"** to **'**)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/JSFiles/jQuery.js")%>'></script>
```